# "react scripts" are not internal or external command executed by a program or batch file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Everything worked fine until at one point I downloaded updates from the git repository. After running I get the message "react scripts" are not internal or external command executed by a program or batch file.

I tried `npm start`, but that gives the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\ganie\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\start\drink-and-talk_frontend-1> npm start

> drink-and-talk_frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

"react-scripts" is not internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file.
PS C:\Users\ganie\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\start\drink-and-talk_frontend-1>
```

I decided to install this dependency directly through `npm install react-scripts` but it still did not help. I installed the latest version of node 19.7.0 and updated the package manager.

Removing `node_modules` and then installing via npm install doesn't seem to fix things. If I run the `npm start` command I get the same error again.

I also checked package.json, but everything is fine there at first glance, here is the configuration:

```json
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "tailwind-config-viewer": "tailwind-config-viewer -o"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwind-config-viewer": "^1.7.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean, though? If `npm` can't see a script, it throws an error. If the script _does_ exist, it runs it, and then your code either errors out or succeeds, but in both cases there will be console output. So: what did the console say? (and remember to [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added an explanation to the question

Comment: Don't use "upd", just rewrite the post to include those details, new readers have no idea what the post used to look like, and shouldn't need to =) That said, also [do not include pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask). Just put the text directly in your post, with some code fences around it. The posting guidelines literally tell you this in big, bold text =)

Comment: I can't add images without a link, I need experience to be more than 10 :(

Comment: Read the comment again, and then read the posting guidelines: It tells you **not** to use images of text (and that includes links that _go_ to images of text). You're trying to show people console output, which is just text, so: copy and paste that into your post. It's text: you can _always_ post text, even at 1 rep =)

Comment: noted, corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like related with node modules since you are saying it was working fine. Delete `node_modules` and do `npm install` , it should fix the problem

Comment: this is more of a comment than answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it turned out that my version of the node is very different from the version of the node of my colleagues. Therefore, I had to downgrade the node version in order to run correctly. To change the version of the node, it was necessary to register `nvm install 16.16.0` and `nvm use 16.16.0` Thanks to everyone who tried to solve my problem! Have a nice day, everyone!

Comment: That's not really a "solution" so much as it side-steps the problem. If switching Node versions fixes it, then so does deleting `node_modules`, and then running `npm cache clean --force` (because npm does not cache dependencies per Node version)  followed by `npm install`.